# CakePHP layout not changing

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working in CakePHP 2.3.0, I developed app using default layout. Now I need to change the layout to `design.ctp` but the app is rendering `default.ctp`

```
    public function myfun() {
      $this -> layout = 'design';

    }
```

I tried to clear the cache and switched ON the debug mode but the app is still picking the `default.ctp`

Comment: Please mention any error you are getting after changing debug mode to 2

Comment: @SubodhGhulaxe There are no errors... Everything works fine, changes also get updated but the design remains as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
class MyTestController extends AppController {
    var $layout = 'default';
```

and in your action try

```
public function myfun() {
  $this->layout = 'design';
}
```

Now, your view will use design.ctp, which is stored in views/layouts/.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I am using this syntax only.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... Actually I have mistakenly called default layout at the bottom of the function.

Answer (score 0):

$this->layout = false;
comment above line and it will work fine if you are palcing your lay